# Typescript cannot destruct union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a union type `Actions` which is

```
type Actions = Readonly<{
    type: ActionTypes.LOAD_POST;
    payload: string;
}> | Readonly<{
    type: ActionTypes.LOAD_POST_FAIL;
    payload: string;
}> | Readonly<{
    type: ActionTypes.LOAD_POST_SUCCESS;
    payload: {
        url: string;
        post: Post;
    };
}>
```

(This is the generated type, the original was nested with multiple types and ReturnType.) ActionTypes is a string enum.

```
const postReducer = (state = initialPostState, action: Actions): PostState => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOAD_POST_SUCCESS: {
      const { post } = action.payload; // No error
      return { ...state, loading: false, success: true, post };
    }
  }

  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOAD_POST: {
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    }
    case ActionTypes.LOAD_POST_SUCCESS: {
      // [ts] Type 'string | { url: string; post: IFullPost; }' has no property 'post' and no string index signature.
      const { post } = payload;
      return { ...state, loading: false, success: true, post };
    }
    case ActionTypes.LOAD_POST_FAIL: {
      return { ...state, loading: false, success: false, post: null };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Why does the first one work but not the second one?

Answer (score 3):

It's by design. Here is a very simplified example:

```
type Actions =
    {
        type: 1,
        payload: string;
    } |
    {
        type: 2,
        payload: { a: string }
    }

function r(action: Actions) {
    const { type } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 2: {
            // Type 'string | { a: string; }' has no property 'a' and no string index signature.
            const { a } = action.payload;
        }

    }
}
```

When we destruct `action` object: `const { type, payload } = action;` **we lose coupling information of destructed types**. After this, `type` constant will have `1 | 2` type and `payload` will have `string | { a: string; }`, i.e. each type will union all possible options based on `Actions` type. This is why TS cannot figure out the exact type of `payload`, because in the `switch` condition we have absolutely separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch on `action.type` in order for the `action.payload` to change its *type* in the case statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing TypeScript reaching the limits of its type inference by [type guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html).

In your non-working example, TypeScript can not infer anything about the already destructured variable `payload`, although it would be technically doable. 
I guess type guards only work on objects directly/literally involved in the guarding expression.